# Prefab can't accept script-created material

Tags: unity, c#

I am doing mod support for my game. I want users to be able to change materials of any prefab in the game. In order to achieve that, I create a new material from the imported data and then apply it to an existing prefab.

However, it does not work. It works if I try to assign the newly created material to an object on the scene (not a prefab) and it works if I try to assign an existing material to a prefab. However, assigning a new material to a prefab results in this:

[image: No material assigned.]

I am fairly certain that is exactly the issue since it can be reproduced as easily as with this snippet of code:

```
GameObject prefab = Resources.Load("Prefabs/Cubes/IceCube") as GameObject;
prefab.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().sharedMaterial = new Material(Shader.Find("Standard"));
```

What am I doing wrong? How can that be worked around?

Comment: It is not recommended to modify materials returned by sharedMaterial. If you want to modify the material of a renderer use material instead.
And if you want to permanently edit the prefab, you could make a new one that gets later loaded (to preserve the original in case user wants to reset his changes) 
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PrefabUtility.SaveAsPrefabAsset.html

Comment: I don't need to edit it permanently, but I need to apply changes to the prefab itself. I don't know what the change will be - it's up to whoever will mod the game.

Comment: PrefabUtility is an Editor only feature. I need to edit prefab on runtime in a standalone build.